# Android : How to change a value into a drawable xml file?

Tags: android

I have this code into a drawable xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Background circle for the magnitude value -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="@color/magnitude1" />
    <size
        android:width="36dp"
        android:height="36dp" />
    <corners android:radius="18dp" />
</shape>
```

And I wanted to change programmatically the value of the solid-->color field
magnitude1 by another one

I tried access to by using

```
 Resources res = this.getContext().getResources();
    myShape = res.getDrawable(magnitude_circle);
```

But Can't achieve to change magnitude1 by magnitude2 for example

Any idea ?

Regards,

Dam

Comment: try my updated solution. It is working in my demo.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `R.drawable.magnitude_circle` instead of only `magnitude_circle` in :

```
 Resources res = this.getContext().getResources();
    myShape = res.getDrawable(magnitude_circle);
```

Comment: I just need after that, to get access to the  <solid android:color="@color/magnitude1" /> field

Answer (score 0):

1.First select the layout where you have used

```
View mainContainer = findViewById(R.id.main_container);
```

2.Then select the background drawable of that container

```
GradientDrawable bgDrawable = (GradientDrawable) mainContainer.getBackground();
```

4. Finally change the color of drawable resource

```
shape.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.magnitude2));
```

Comment: Yep  I Tried like this :  `code View mainContainer = findViewById(textView_magnitude);

 GradientDrawable bgDrawable = (GradientDrawable) mainContainer.getBackground();
        bgDrawable.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.magnitude2));code`  then get an error --> _java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.view.View.getBackground()' on a null object reference_ @MKY

Comment: it is clear that you have given wrong resource id in first line.
replace `R.id.main_container` by your resource id on which you want to set the background drawable

Comment: are you using it in activity layout or fragment ?

Comment: The last try I reffer to was done in an activity .........my TextView look like this    `code <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_magnitude"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/magnitude_circle"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="eee"/>  code`

Comment: you have given View `mainContainer = findViewById(textView_magnitude); `instead of that give like this `View mainContainer = findViewById(R.id.textView_magnitude);` . you have forgot R.id.

Comment: The error is still the same :-( ...........  I will get into it tomorrow , maybe some idea will come during the sleep  :-)

Comment: find the bug .............I had to put the code in the adapter and define a context in the adapter constructor , then it works ,,,,, I can go to sleep without having nightmare :-))  thank  you guys , have a good day !